# Retargetting solution has no effect

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, target-platform

I have installed the latest Windows 10 SDK from here:
https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

When I try to rebuild my solution, I get the error "MSB8036 The Windows SDK version 10.0.10069.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".

That is what I did:
[image]

The IDE tells me: "Retargeting End: 2 completed, 0 failed, 0 skipped".

However, when I then try to rebuild the solution, I'm getting the same error again.

Does anybody have any hint how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, I switched the "Platform Toolset" in the voice project from "Visual Studio 2015 (v140)" to "Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)" (which I wanted anyway), and now it works.

I guess that doesn't solve the problem for anybody who has the same problem, but in my case it solved the problem.

Comment: I didn't even see the dropdown you saw in one Solution I was working with (Interactive Brokers API Client). Rt-clicking project->Configuration Properties->General->Platform Toolset change here and then retrying rt-click Retarget Project or Solution got a successful build! Probably doing something wrong, but what a waste of time

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem... Auto migrating didn't work, but changing at:
properties ->Configuration properties -> windows SDK version

Probably the auto config didn't work while there was some other bug in the code which prevented the compiler to "take effect" or so.

Comment: Similar thing worked for me: Platform toolset instead of Win SDK ver and then retrying retarget.

Answer (score 0):

Remove from ".vcxproj" files following strings:

```
<VCTargetsPath Condition="'$(VCTargetsPath11)' != '' and '$(VSVersion)' == '' and $(VisualStudioVersion) == ''">$(VCTargetsPath11)</VCTargetsPath>
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10069.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit off the bat that this isn't the 'correct' solution.

But I was able to solve a similar issue by downloading the older SDK.  I originally couldn't find it in Window's archives but I was able to find it by going to 'Add/Remove Programs' and then select visual studios and click modify.

Scroll through the list of SDKs and check the one you need.

Again, I realize this does not solve the symptom described above but this may solve the underlining issue for others who stumble here like I did.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Visual Studio 2015, retargetting didn't work, appeared to do nothing. I fixed this by deleting all of my cache data and running `devenv /resetuserdata`.

**See here:** https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/

After this, I was able to retarget again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because the project was readonly.  It merely pretended to change it but actually did nothing (and changed it in the properties dialog).